# Accessing Estimator evaluation results via SessionRunHooks

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I'm trying to modify a program that uses the Estimator class in TensorFlow (v1.10) and I would like to access the evaluation metric results every time evaluation occurs so that I can copy the checkpoint files only when a new maximum has been achieved.

One idea I had was to create a class inheriting from `SessionRunHook`, doing the work I want in the `after_run` method. According to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.10/api_docs/python/tf/train/SessionRunHook) I can specify what is passed to `after_run` using `before_run`. However I cannot find a way to access the evaluation metrics results I want from the information passed in to `before_run`.

I looked into the `Estimator` code and it appears that it is [writing the results to a summary file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4dcfddc5d12018a5a0fdca652b9221ed95e9eb23/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py#L1669) so another idea I had was to read this back in the `after_run` method, but the [summary api](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.10/api_docs/python/tf/summary) doesn't seem to provide any read operations.

Are there any other ways I can achieve what I want to do? Not using the `Estimator` class is not an option as that would involve drastic changes to the code I'm working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkpoints are not the same as exporting. Checkpoints are about fault-recovery and involve saving the complete training state (weights, global step number, etc.).

In your case I would recommend exporting. The exported model will written to a directory called “exporter” and the serving input function specifies what the end-user will be expected to provide to the prediction service.

You can use the class "Best Exporter" to just export the models that are perfoming best:

> https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/BestExporter

This class exports the serving graph and checkpoints of the best models.

Also, it performs a model export everytime when the new model is better than any exsiting model.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like it'll do the job so I'll accept your answer and award you the bounty. I still find it hard to believe that the Estimator API doesn't provide easy access to the evaluation metrics. It seems like something that many users would want.